# How can I replace all classes that start with "border-" using gsub?

Tags: html, css, regex, ruby, gsub

I'm currently doing this which works great

`html_tag.gsub("border-gray-300", "border-red-500")`

I now need to `gsub` anything that follows `border-` with `border-red-500`

For example `border-gray-500` or `border-blue-50` need to all return `border-red-500`. I'm not good with regular expressions yet, could someone help me get started?

Comment: You can try `html_tag.gsub(/border-[a-z]+-\d+\b/,"border-red-500")`

Comment: You need to be more specific about the form of strings that you wish to convert. I assume they all begin with `"border-"`, but what about `"border-gray-1000"`, `"border-yellow-1000"`, `"border-yellow-1000"`, `"border-Gray-500"`, `"border-collie"`, and so on. Providing a few examples in not a substitute for a precise statement of the question in words. For example you may wish to replace strings of  the form `border-XXX-YYY` where `XXX` represents <?> and `YYY` represents <?>.

Comment: @cary the only constraint is that the word needs to start with "border-" so "border-collie" will be replaced with "border-red-500" but "focus:border-indigo-500" with be left alone

Comment: Will `"border-collie or pug"` become `"border-red-100 or pug"` or `"border-red-100"`? In the latter case the space character has significance, but you've said nothing about that. To clarify your question it's best to edit the question, rather than elaborate in comments, as questions should stand alone, in part because not all readers read all comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Define Data Samples

Your original question lacks precision (e.g. are we talking about inline style attributes, style tags, or CSS properties?) and a valid, testable example of what to include/exclude. So, let's create one. For example:

```rb
# here-document containing style and class tags
# that we can use as a test fixture
html_tag = <<~'INLINE_STYLES'
    <h1 style="border-color: lightgrey;"></h1>
    <h2 class="border-red-500"></h2>
    <h3 style="foo; border-collie;"></h3>
    <h4 class="focus:border-indigo-500"></h4>
    <h5 style="border-style: 1px;"></h5>
    <h6 class="border-collie" style="border: 5px solid red;">border-</h6>
INLINE_STYLES
```

Given this sample data, you can see why defining test inputs and expected outputs is important. What should your expression do with `border-style`? Should we ignore it because it's a style attribute rather than a class? Or should that be changed as well? For this answer, we'll assume that you only want to change classes and not inline styles, attributes inside a style tag, or external CSS files.

### Differentiating Styles from Classes

You'll likely have to do some tuning to the program logic and regular expression below based on your real target data, because "the simplest thing that could possibly work" often changes when the data does. There is unlikely to be a single canonical solution that handles every possible edge case.

With that in mind, you could use the following with the sample data above:

```
border_class_tag =
  /
    (          # capture group \1 for replacement string
      class="  #   class attribute with opening doublequote
      .*?      #   non-greedy match until...
    )
               # text to be replaced, a.k.a. \&
    (?<!:)     #   not immediately preceded by a colon
    border-    #   a class that starts with "border-"
    [^"]+      #   anything not a closing doublequote

    (?=")      # immediately followed by a doublequote
  /ix  
puts html_tag.gsub border_class_tag, '\1border-red-500'
```

This will render the following on standard output:

```html
<h1 style="border-color: lightgrey;"></h1>
<h2 class="border-red-500"></h2>
<h3 style="foo; border-collie;"></h3>
<h4 class="focus:border-indigo-500"></h4>
<h5 style="border-style: 1px;"></h5>
<h6 class="border-red-500" style="border: 5px solid red;">border-</h6>
```

This looks right to me given the expectations and samples defined. Your mileage may vary.